# Adding signals to class that inherit from QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qobject

I want to add a signal to a class that inherits from `QGraphicsScene`.

```
signals:
    void update(std::vector< std::vector<int> > board);
```

When I do this, Qt Creator warns me that I forgot the `Q_OBJECT` macro. But somewhere I read that since `QGraphicsScene` doesn't inherit from `QObject`, I shouldn't put it in my class definition. But signals need this macro.

How do I add a signal to a class that doesn't inherit from `QObject`?

---

**boardgui.h**

```
#ifndef BOARDGUI_H
#define BOARDGUI_H
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

class BoardGUI : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    BoardGUI(QGraphicsView*& view, int dimension);
    ~BoardGUI();
    void buildBoard();
signals:
    void update(std::vector< std::vector<int> > board);
private:
    int dimension;
    QGraphicsView* view;
};

#endif // BOARDGUI_H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting as answer, as requested:

Is update() your signal? did you try to implement the signal yourself? If yes, don't do that, signals are defined by moc.

Answer (score 2):

QGraphicsScene does inherit from QObject.  You can consult the documentation. 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html

Comment: So I should be able to add the macro then? If I do that, I get these compiler errors: http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/7995/errorsv.jpg What is a vtable?

Comment: I did some research... if the vtable if giving errors, something must be going wrong with the runtime binding.

Comment: Make sure you do a full clean and rebuild after making this sort of change.  I've seen QtCreator get confused when it has wrongly cached some old information about what has signals and what doesn't.  Also, make sure the headers section of your .pro file is correct, and study how moc acts to make sure your .pro file will make it do what it needs to.

Comment: I haven't manually tinkered with my .pro file so unless Qt Creator made a glitch it should be okay, right? I did a cleanup (right-click project, then "Clean Project") but that didn't help.

Comment: @Pieter: maybe a shot in the dark, but be sure to run qmake as well (it's an option in the build menu in QtCreator), moc needs to be run on Q_OBJECT classes, and QtCreator might forget that :).

Comment: I ran qmake and now *error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status* is the only error, so something went wrong during the linking but it's not telling me what.

Comment: Check that your .h file is listed in the HEADERS section of your .pro file. Then rerun qmake.

Comment: Yes, it is listed in the .pro file.

Answer (score 1):

Vtables have something to do with virtual functions. When you have an error like `Undefined reference to vtable` then it cannot find an implementation for a virtual function (I think). Have you implemented all of your functions? Maybe you used the `virtual` keyword when you weren't supposed to? Or vice versa?

Also, you say that you want to add a signal, but your code chunk shows a slot? Could you show a little more of your class?

Comment: undefined references to vtable errors in gcc are indeed most commonly due to missing implemententations of virtual functions in a class.

Comment: Whoops, yes, I did in fact intend to use a signal. I'm still getting the same error though. I added the class's header file to my question.

Comment: Try changing `signals:` to `private signals:` or `public signals:` depending on if you want the `update` signal to be public or not. Although, I think it might just inherit the `private:` from above.

Comment: private signals:, public signals: doesn't work, neither syntactically nor semantically. signals is a define for "protected".

Comment: I changed `signals` to `public signals` (see updated code). I did a cleanup, I ran qmake and then I built the project. This is the error I got: *expected ':' before 'protected'* (boardgui.h:13)

Comment: @Frank: you're right, the docs confirm this. If I change it back to `signals`, I get a generic linker error. If I look at the compiler output, I can see this alarming line: *./debug\moc_boardgui.o:C:\Users\Pieter\Documents\My Dropbox\Unief\OOP\QtChess-build-desktop/debug/moc_boardgui.cpp:82: multiple definition of `BoardGUI::update(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >)'* I'm pretty sure I only defined it once though.

Comment: Is update() your signal? did you try to implement the signal yourself? If yes, don't do that, signals are defined by moc.

Comment: D'oh. You pointed out some oddities in my code. Sheesh, I didn't know what I was thinking... Anyhow, if you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not implemented any class with Q_Object before to the project and you add the Q_OBJECT line yourself, you get the vtable error. If you add another c++ class to the project that inherits from QObject, then you get rid of this problem. You can remove this class you created if you dont need it. I am not sure why this happens, but this is easy way to get rid of the problem. Maybe the creator adds some line to the . pro file when you add a class that inherits from qobject.

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented your destructor? If not, try changing `~BoardGUI();` to `~BoardGUI(){};`

Comment: The trailing ";" is useless and will give a warning depending on your compiler.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the destructor in `boardgui.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added boardgui.h to the MOC preprocessor's file list?  Any class that uses QObject and Signals/Slots needs to be passed through the Meta-Object Compiler so it can generate the actual code behind the signals.

I am unsure if Qt Creator handles this automatically.

Comment: I think it does handle that automatically. From the docs: *For anything but the simplest test programs, it is recommended that you automate running the moc. By adding some rules to your program's makefile, make can take care of running moc when necessary and handling the moc output. We recommend using the qmake makefile generation tool for building your makefiles. This tool generates a makefile that does all the necessary moc handling.*

Comment: @Pieter Interesting. Does that include figuring out which of your header files actually need MOC generation based on their contents? Or does it just MOC them all? I use CMake to generate my build files, and I can call the MOC macros, but I still need to pass them a list of header files that need MOC generation

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to inherit from `QObject` yourself.

**boardgui.h**

```
#ifndef BOARDGUI_H
#define BOARDGUI_H
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>

class BoardGUI : public QObject, public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    BoardGUI(QGraphicsView*& view, int dimension);
    ~BoardGUI();
    void buildBoard();
signals:
    void update(std::vector< std::vector<int> > board);
private:
    int dimension;
    QGraphicsView* view;
};

#endif // BOARDGUI_H
```

If you are using *Qt Creator*, you shouldn't have to worry about moc, everything should be handled by *Qt Creator*.